# How to create union class structure?

Tags: c++, class, boost

Say class A had method `do();` and class B had field `data;`. I wonder if there is a way (using Boost for example) to create a class union from A and B which would have method `do()` and field `data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Union has a specific meaning in c and c++, and it's not what you want. It sounds like you want is multiple inheritance, a class `C` that inherits from both `A` and `B`. Alternatively, you could also have a class `C` that contains instances of classes `A` and `B`. Oftentimes composition ("has-a") is preferable over inheritance ("is-a").

Comment: Note that it's possible to give a union member functions, so that although a union will not _automatically_ acquire member functions of any of its class-type members, you can explicitly create the ones you want. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5275997/322333) for an example of union member functions.

Answer (score 0):

Not a chance in hell. This would require reflection, which does not currently exist in the C++ language, and even if it did, it's highly unlikely that anybody would have implemented such a thing because why would you even want to do that. The closest you can get is if you inherited from both classes.